# 2D array is truncating some characters

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I just need to know how to fix this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define PRICE 1985.95
#define MAX_LENGTH 20
#define MAX_EMPLOYEES 25
#define MAX_WEEKS 7

void getNames(int* employeeNumber, char names[][MAX_LENGTH]);
void getSales(int* employeeNumber,int* weeksNumber, int weeks[][MAX_WEEKS+1]);

void calcEachTotal(int empNumber, int weekNumber, int weeks[][MAX_WEEKS+1]);
void calcTotal(int,int,int*,int [][MAX_WEEKS+1],int [][3]);
void calcCoTot(int ,int*, int [][3]);

void outputDataScreen(int,int,int,char [][MAX_LENGTH],int [][MAX_WEEKS+1], int [][3]);
void outputDataFile(int,int,int,char [][MAX_LENGTH],int [][MAX_WEEKS+1], int [][3]);

int main (void)
{
    char employees[MAX_EMPLOYEES][MAX_LENGTH] = {{0}};
    //holds personal sales info and each employees total sales
    int sales[MAX_EMPLOYEES][MAX_WEEKS+1]={{0}};
    //holds the weekly lowest,highest and total
    int weeklyStats[MAX_WEEKS][3] = {{0}};
    int employeeNumber;
    int weeksNumber;
    int companyTotal = 0;



    getNames(&employeeNumber,employees);
    getSales(&employeeNumber, &weeksNumber,sales);
    calcEachTotal(employeeNumber, weeksNumber, sales);
    //call function to calculate personal,weekly and company total sales
    calcTotal(employeeNumber,weeksNumber,&companyTotal,sales,weeklyStats);
    calcCoTot(weeksNumber,&companyTotal, weeklyStats);
    //call two functions to output the data to the screen and the output text file
    outputDataScreen(employeeNumber,weeksNumber,companyTotal,employees,sales,weeklyStats);
    outputDataFile(employeeNumber,weeksNumber,companyTotal,employees,sales,weeklyStats);




    return 1;


}


/*===============getNames======================
Pre : NAMES.txt is an open file.
Post : Number of employees
This function will read the number of emplyees
and close if there is more than 25 employees
*/


void getNames(int* employeeNumber, char names[][MAX_LENGTH])
{

    FILE* spNames;

    int i;
    int j;

// statements
    spNames = fopen("/Users/r3spectak/Desktop/NAMES.TXT", "r");

    if (!spNames)
        {
        printf("Could not open  NAMES.txt\n\n");
        exit(100);
        }

    fscanf(spNames,"%d",employeeNumber);

    if (*employeeNumber > MAX_EMPLOYEES )
        {
        printf("Unable to read more than 25 employees\n\n");
        exit(100);
        }

    for(i = 0; i< *employeeNumber;i++)
        for(j = 0; j<= MAX_LENGTH; j++)
            fscanf(spNames,"%c", &names[i][j]);




    fclose(spNames);


}

/*=====getSales==============
Pre : SALES.txt is an open file.
number of week and employee number with the array of weeks.
Post : number of weeks
This function reads the number of weaks and close
*/

void getSales(int* employeeNumber,int* weeksNumber, int weeks[][MAX_WEEKS+1])
{
// Local variables
    FILE* spSales;

    int i;
    int j;

// Statements
    spSales = fopen("/Users/r3spectak/Desktop/SALES.TXT", "r");

    if (!spSales)
        {
        printf("Could not open Sales.txt\n\n");
        exit(102);
        }

    fscanf(spSales,"%d",weeksNumber);

    if (*weeksNumber > MAX_WEEKS)
        {
        printf("Unable to read more than 6 weeks\n\n");
        exit(102);
        }

    for(i = 0 ; i < *employeeNumber;i++)
        for(j = 0 ; j < *weeksNumber ; j++)
            fscanf(spSales,"%d", &weeks[i][j]);

    fclose(spSales);
}


/*===========calcEachTotal====================
Pre : Number of employees, Number of weeks
Post : Employee total
This function calculates the weekly total for each employee and store in an array
*/
void calcEachTotal(int employeeNumber, int weekNumber, int weeks[][MAX_WEEKS+1])
{

// Local Variables
    int i;
    int j;

// Statements
    for(i = 0; i< employeeNumber; i++)
        for(j=0, weeks[i][MAX_WEEKS] = 0; j< weekNumber;j++)
            weeks[i][MAX_WEEKS] += weeks[i][j];

}
/*===========calcTotal====================
Pre : the number of the employees and the weeks , two arrays that hold the names and sales info and Stats array which is for weekly low,high and total
Post : calculates the weekly total for each employee. the highest, lowest and the total of each week and the company total and stores them in the arrays
This function
*/

void calcTotal(int employeeNumber, int weekNumber,int *companyTotal, int weeks[][MAX_WEEKS+1],int stats[][3])
{
// Local Variables
    int i;
    int j;

// Statements
    //calculate the weekly highest, lowest and total and store it in the stats array
    for (i = 0 ; i<weekNumber ; i++)
    {
        stats[i][0]=weeks[0][i];
        stats[i][1]=weeks[0][i];
        stats[i][2]=0;
        for (j=0; j <employeeNumber; j++)
        {
            if (weeks[j][i] > stats[i][0])
                stats[i][0] = weeks[j][i];

            if (weeks[j][i] < stats[i][1])
                stats[i][1] = weeks[j][i];

            stats[i][2] += weeks[i][j];

        }
    }

}

/*===========calcCoTot====================
Pre : the number of the employees and the weeks , two arrays that hold the names and sales info and Stats array which is for weekly low,high and total
Post : calculates the weekly total for each employee. the highest, lowest and the total of each week and the company total and stores them in the arrays
This function
*/

void calcCoTot(int weekNumber,int *companyTotal, int stats[][3])
{
// Local Variables
    int i;
    int j;


    //calculate the company total
    for( i = 0; i < weekNumber ; i++)
        *companyTotal += stats[i][2];

}

//===============outputDataScreen========
/*
pre : the number of the workers and weeks, a char array that holds the names , an int array for personal sales and
    another int array stats which holds weekly info , also another int for company total
post : outputs all the information in a table to the screen
*/

void outputDataScreen(int empNum,int weeks,int companyTotal,char names[][MAX_LENGTH],int sales[][MAX_WEEKS+1], int stats[][3])

{
// Local Variables
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;

// Statements
    printf("\t\tHomework 2: Two Dimensional Arrays\n");
    printf(" *** Sales Table *** \n\n");

    printf("=============\t\t");
    for ( i = 0; i < weeks; i++)
        printf("======\t");

    printf("\nSalesperson\t\t");

    for ( i = 0; i<weeks; i++)
        printf("Week%d\t",i+1);

    printf("\n=============\t\t");

    for ( i = 0; i < weeks; i++)
        printf("======\t");

    for ( i = 0 ; i < empNum ; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0 ; j<= MAX_LENGTH; j++)
            printf("%c",names[i][j]);
        //printf("");

        for(k = 0; k < weeks;k++)
            printf("\t%d",(int)sales[i][k]);
    }

    printf("\n*** The output is in OUTPUT.TXT ***\n\t\t\tEnd of the program!\n\t\t\tHave a great day!\n");


}


//===============outputDataFile=======
/*
pre : the number of the workers and weeks, a char array that holds the names , an int array for personal sales and
    another int array stats which holds weekly info , also another int for company total
post : outputs all the information in a table to the File
*/

void outputDataFile(int empNum,int weeks,int companyTotal,char names[][MAX_LENGTH],int sales[][MAX_WEEKS+1], int stats[][3])

{
// Local Variables
    FILE* fpOut;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;



    //open the txt file to output the information
// Statements
    fpOut = fopen("/Users/r3spectak/Desktop/OUTPUT.TXT","w");

    fprintf(fpOut,"\t\tHomework 2: Two Dimensional Arrays\n");
    fprintf(fpOut," *** Sales Table *** \n\n");
    fprintf(fpOut,"Number of Employees: %d\n",empNum);
    fprintf(fpOut,"Number of Weeks: %d\n\n",weeks);

    fprintf(fpOut,"Personal sales info\n");


    fprintf(fpOut,"=============\t\t");
    for ( i = 0; i < weeks; i++)
        fprintf(fpOut,"======\t");

    fprintf(fpOut,"\nSalesperson\t\t");

    for ( i = 0; i<weeks; i++)
        fprintf(fpOut,"Week%d\t",i+1);

    fprintf(fpOut,"\n=============\t\t");

    for ( i = 0; i < weeks; i++)
        fprintf(fpOut,"======\t");



    for ( i = 0 ; i < empNum ; i++)
    {

        for ( j = 0 ; j < MAX_LENGTH ; j++)
            fprintf(fpOut,"%c",names[i][j]);
        fprintf(fpOut," ");

        for(k = 0 ; k < weeks;k++)
            fprintf(fpOut,"%-.2f  ",(double)sales[i][k]*PRICE);

        fprintf(fpOut,"%-.2f ",(double)sales[i][MAX_WEEKS]*PRICE);

        fprintf(fpOut,"*\n");


    }

    fprintf(fpOut,"\n\nWEEKLY INFO :\n\n");

    fprintf(fpOut,"HIGHEST SALE         ");

    for (i=0 ; i < weeks ; i++ )
        fprintf(fpOut,"%-.2f  ",(double)stats[i][0]*PRICE);

    fprintf(fpOut,"\n");

    fprintf(fpOut,"LOWEST SALE          ");

    for (i=0 ; i < weeks ; i++ )
        fprintf(fpOut,"%-.2f  ",(double)stats[i][1]*PRICE);

    fprintf(fpOut,"\n");


        fprintf(fpOut,"WEEKLY TOTAL         ");

    for (i=0 ; i < weeks ; i++ )
        fprintf(fpOut,"%-.2f  ",(double)stats[i][2]*PRICE);

    fprintf(fpOut,"\nCOMPANY TOTAL SALES : %-.2lf\n\n",(double)companyTotal*PRICE);

    fclose(fpOut);


}
```

NAMES.txt

```
    16
    Kelly, Victor       
    Lam, Gary           
    Nagasake, David     
    Nguyen, Jeff        
    Nguyen, Michael     
    Sinn, Scott         
    Smith, Jacob        
    Son, Thai           
    Tavares, Maribel    
    Tran, Diane         
    Tsukamoto, Andrew   
    Wang, Mary          
    Young, Daniel       
    Wells, Steve        
    Wong, Justin        
    Johnson, Mary
```

SALES.txt

```
    4
    25 20 25 25
    20 22 23 22
    25 26 25 22
    30 28 25 26
    25 30 45 20
    30 25 20 21
    27 25 24 26
    20 23 24 20
    28 26 24 25
    30 10 35 32
    28 29 30 35
    15 16 15 14
    12 15 12 19
    20 24 20 18
    10 15 12 16
    32 30 33 29
```

The program works and all but im getting a problem with the array. it is not printing it right. the order of the characters is running over the place and some names are truncated.
Is there something wrong with the declaration of the arrays? or do i have to print white space? someone please help me!

OUTPUT.txt

```
 *** Sales Table *** 

Number of Employees: 16
Number of Weeks: 4

Personal sales info
=============       ======  ======  ======  ======  
Salesperson     Week1   Week2   Week3   Week4   
=============       ======  ======  ======  ======  
Kelly, Victor      49648.75  39719.00  49648.75  49648.75  188665.25 *

Lam, Gary         39719.00  43690.90  45676.85  43690.90  172777.65 *

Nagasake, David  49648.75  51634.70  49648.75  43690.90  194623.10 *

Nguyen, Jeff    59578.50  55606.60  49648.75  51634.70  216468.55 *

Nguyen, Michae 49648.75  59578.50  89367.75  39719.00  238314.00 *

Sinn, Scott   59578.50  49648.75  39719.00  41704.95  190651.20 *

Smith, Jacob 53620.65  49648.75  47662.80  51634.70  202566.90 *

Son, Thai   39719.00  45676.85  47662.80  39719.00  172777.65 *

Tavares, M 55606.60  51634.70  47662.80  49648.75  204552.85 *
ribel    
Tran, Dia 59578.50  19859.50  69508.25  63550.40  212496.65 *
e         
Tsukamot 55606.60  57592.55  59578.50  69508.25  242285.90 *
, Andrew   
Wang, M 29789.25  31775.20  29789.25  27803.30  119157.00 *
ry          
Young, 23831.40  29789.25  23831.40  37733.05  115185.10 *
Daniel       
Wells 39719.00  47662.80  39719.00  35747.10  162847.90 *
 Steve        
Wong 19859.50  29789.25  23831.40  31775.20  105255.35 *
 Justin        
Joh 63550.40  59578.50  65536.35  57592.55  246257.80 *


WEEKLY INFO :

HIGHEST SALE         63550.40  59578.50  89367.75  69508.25  
LOWEST SALE          19859.50  19859.50  23831.40  27803.30  
WEEKLY TOTAL         722885.80  734801.50  822183.30  909565.10  
COMPANY TOTAL SALES : 3189435.70
```

Comment: This question is too long and vague; please reduce the size of the problem and ask a specific question, for example, I would try with only one name/sales, say what output I'm expecting, and what output I get instead.

Comment: how is it vague?! the problem is right above you. the names are not printed properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you read the names you didn't read only as long as the name was,
you always read MAX_LENGTH chars.  So the first employee name doesn't end
when you think it does... it is always MAX_LENGTH chars.
Also, you never null terminated your strings... names[i][j] = '\0'.

```
for(i = 0; i< *employeeNumber;i++)
        for(j = 0; j<= MAX_LENGTH; j++)
            fscanf(spNames,"%c", &names[i][j]);
```

Why are you using scanf?  It's always been a source of pain for me.
Try using fgets().. to read the line.  Line based IO is better.
If you use scanf("%c") I don't know what it does with the newline.

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);

    for(i = 0; i< *employeeNumber;i++) {
       fgets(names[i], MAX_LENGTH, spNames);
       // trim the newline from the name (there is probably a better way)
       int len = strlen(names[i]) - 1;   // -1 because len=1 has only index 0
       if (names[i][len] == '\n') names[i][len] = '\0';
    }
```

Comment: why not fgetc? and what is strlen.